# why eigenvalues in upper/lower/diagonal matrices are equal to the diagonal entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

when having such a matrix :

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a & 0  \\
    0 & b  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

eigen values are : a & b

I understand it algebraically , but not geometrically ! What does these types of matrices represent to confirm immediately that their eigenvalue = the diagonal entries ?

I mean what is the proof geometrically?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! please learn JAX, your question is unclear you wish to have a geometric interpretation? or do you want a proof/derivation to what you are claiming?

Comment: Actually I need the geometric interpretation !

Comment: Are you familiar with the definition of a basis (at least in $\mathbb{R}^2)$?

Comment: The first problem you will have is to interpret a diagonal matrix geometrically.The second problem is what is the geometrical definition of eigenvector and eigenvalue pairs. The third problem is the geometrical definition of a basis. Can you do these? Is this what your question asks for?

Comment: yes these what  I am searching for!